# CakePHP: Full blown internationalized web application

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Can any one point to resources for internationalizing a web application using CakePHP.

Opinions differ, but I personally feel that the documentation for CakePHP on i18n is not up to the mark [please don't post your opinions though].

A full blown example will definitely be quite handy! Any resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into the source code of a available cakephp application (maybe [croogo](http://www.croogo.org))